# Actions on Google - Push notification to a user (userId strategy)

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am working on my push notifications to users and working through the documentation.

1. Following [this](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications) walk through, I have set up a webhook to send a notification to a user, this notes a `target.userId` for the recipient. Question, what exact value is the referring to? Is this the userId I invent for a user, or is it something else?
2. Looking at userId documentation, it appears this has to be generated/maintained, and can go stale every 30 days of inactivity. Noted [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info)

My concern is - users sending other users notifications. If the recipients userId has gone stale from what I've stored in my database, I assume the push notification will fail when trying to find that user by userId that expired? Is this the only way to target a user for a push notification? My assumption is yes based on [this](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#target) documentation - but it seems brittle - or unstable, since it rely's on an ID that can expire (unless i'm misunderstanding userId's).

Is what I've outlined above the correct way to think about push notifications from one user to another? I store the users ID in my database, and when a message is triggered ie: "tell JimBob that I'll be there at 11." i look through my DB to find JimBob and his saved userId, and then send JimBob the push Notification from MarySue.

I assume this also denotes that JimBob has to allow push notifications from the intent "receive_message".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you're misunderstanding the ID that is sent to you.

First - the UserID you reference is deprecated and scheduled to be removed later this year. And even when it wasn't deprecated, it would be unique and non-duplicated, so there was little chance of missends.

The ID that you need to use will be handed to you when the user [approves the subscription](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications#finalize_the_subscription). This will be in the arguments that are sent as part of the Intent where they approve it, and not with the request in general. When sent to you, you need to save this.

Comment: Does this mean that I need to store a different ID for potentially different subscriptions a user approves? Meaning a user could have a potential array of ID's that are assigned for each subscription they have.

Comment: Looking at that page, i assume this is the line to be paying attention to:

`const userID = conv.arguments.get('UPDATES_USER_ID');`

Comment: Yes, that's the ID.

Comment: Is that an ID in reference to all of the users allowed push notifications?